# Zenoh-net subscriber not receiving any data from dds over tcp using python

Tags: python-3.x, ros, data-distribution-service

I have tried receiving the data from ROS-DDS bridge, but not able to receive at the Zenoh server.

whatever is given on zenoh-net, i tried. But of no use.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please give more details on what you've tried so far: - Which version of zenoh-bridge-dds you use ? - Which version of zenoh-python you use ? - Which options did your set running zenoh-bridge-dds ? - Can you show you're Python code declaring the zenoh session and subscription ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that you are using different versions for the python API and the zenoh bridge. You should make sure that the same version is used.

You can also check the examples at https://github.com/eclipse-zenoh/zenoh-demos/tree/master/ROS2

Feel free to reach out the development team on the Zenoh Discord channel if you have more questions (https://discord.gg/cRFZDJfS3g)